# Is HTTPS behind reverse proxy needed?

Tags: security, ssl, nginx, https, server

I have an API server running behind an nginx reverse proxy. It is important to have all requests to my API server be secured via TLS since it handles sensitive data.

I've setup nginx to work with TLS (LetsEncrypt) so that seems to be okay. However, requests from nginx to my API server are still insecure `http` requests (this is all happening across docker containers, by the way).

Is it a best practice to also setup https between the reverse proxy and the API server? If so, how would I go about doing that without over-engineering it?

Comment: Not if it's all inside your secure LAN.

Comment: It is, I'm just asking to know what the best practice is.

Comment: Most times you will terminate SSL at nginx and let it be http to the actual API. This reduces load on your API also as https is heavier then http. If your nginx is not in the same network or you think nginx to API channel is not secure then you may go for a https from nginx to API also. But in usual cases SSL is terminated either at the LB or front facing webserver

Comment: Obvious comment: the need to encrypt between the proxy and the API depends entirely on your threat model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It all comes down to how secure <s>or paranoid</s> you'd like your implementation to be. It may also depend on the type of data you're playing with. For instance: I'd definitely do this for credit card numbers or other sensitive information.

As [the](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47959260#comment82887895_47959260) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47959260#comment82890094_47959260) have already stated, you would typically terminate SSL connections at the front facing webserver, assuming the API backend is also inside your LAN, which you trust and control. If you want to go that extra mile, you could also set up SSL on the API backend. Details of how to do that depend on the software you're using on your backend.

If you do decide to implement SSL on the API backend, the setup would be similar to what you did to setup Nginx with SSL on the frontend, with the main difference being you don't need to use a public certificate on the backend. It can be self-signed, since no one else besides your web server will be talking to it. Then it's just a matter of fixing all the URIs in your code to use HTTPS.

Comment: **Using HTTPS slightly costs performance**, compared to using HTTP. You said “It all comes down to how secure or paranoid you’d like your implementation to be.”, but **_how_ does using HTTPS behind the edge (e.g. reverse proxy) make it more secure?** What exactly does it do to the overall security to be worth the slight performance loss, other than satisfying my perfectionism?

Comment: @КонстантинВан It primarily depends on whether or not the connection between your proxy or load balancer and your backend can be trusted. If they're all in the same subnet that you control, you don't need it, since you can trust all the machines on that subnet. If the connection to the backend is traversing an untrusted network path, then using HTTPS is recommended to protect the privacy and integrity of the transmitted data. There may also be compliance reasons to do so.